# Running docker containers each with socsk5 proxy

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, proxy

**Intro:**
I have an app, when I run it, it connects to a server and shares its bandwidth, (basically gives out the public IP for the server to use),

**Development:**
Now I wanted that app to use transparent socks5 proxy for sending and receiving requests. This was possible when I downloaded the app (non containerized version) on ubuntu and configured red-socks and iptables in it, the server the app connected to assumed the app's public IP was the one I mentioned (socks5://user:pass@ip:port) (i own these proxy IPs too)

**Requirement:**
Next, I wanted to scale it out, so I looked for a docker image of this app, it was available so I downloaded and ran it, it worked fine, but the IP the server received was the non proxy IP (obviously as I have not configured any proxy).

My proposed idea was to run multiple docker containers,
but I still don't know how will I configure a different socks5 proxy for each of these containers.

Can someone advise me on how to go forward with this.
`Thank you in advance :D`

Edits: I had mentioned I was trying to do what I did with the ubuntu system on a ubuntu docker container, removed that and organized the whole situation.

Comment: You approximately can't run `iptables` inside a container.  Usually the container runtime itself (either Docker or Kubernetes) fully manages the network environment.

Comment: I would clean this up, the edits, roll them into the whole situation. There's a lot of information here and it would be nice to have it more organized.

Comment: I have cleaned it up and have given a nice story too

Comment: @DavidMaze i created a dockerfile where i have an entrypoint.sh but the commands being run in that requests root permission , yet if sudo bash is put before that it throws an error